# How to return a negative fraction when subtracting with use of classes?

Tags: python, class, fractions

In part of my code I can subtract fractions, however if I enter (- p) where p is a fraction I get a TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: "Fraction" and "Fraction"

```
def gcd(denominator, numerator):
    if numerator == 0:
        return denominator
    else:
        return gcd(numerator, (denominator % numerator))

class Fraction:
    
    def __init__(self,numerator = 0, denominator = 1):

        self.numerator = int(numerator / gcd(abs(denominator),abs(numerator) ))
        self.denominator = int(denominator / gcd(abs(denominator),abs(numerator) ))
        if self.denominator < 0:
            self.denominator = abs(self.denominator)
            self.numerator = -1*self.numerator
        elif self.denominator == 0:
            raise ZeroDivisionError
        
    def __str__(self):
        if self.denominator == 1:
            return str(self.numerator)
        else:
            return str(self.numerator) + "/" + str(self.denominator)
    
    def __rsub__(self,other):
        return self.__sub__(other)

    def __sub__(self,other):
        if type(other) == int:
            other = Fraction(other,1)
            return self.sub(other)
        else:
            
            return self.sub(other)
    
    def sub(self,other):
        result = Fraction()
        
        result.numerator = other.denominator * self.numerator - self.denominator * other.numerator
        result.denominator = other.denominator * self.denominator
        
        multiple = gcd(result.denominator,result.numerator)
        
        result.numerator = int(result.numerator / multiple)
        result.denominator = int(result.denominator / multiple)
        
        return result

p = Fraction(2,3)

r = (- p)
```

However, when my input is (1 - p) I get the correct output. Suppose p = Fraction(2, 3) then I would like (- p) to return (-2 / 3) or (2/ -3). The problem seems to me to be in the fact that no input is given for the first argument when subtracting. While searching I did come across things like `__neg__`, but I'm still new to python and using classes so I don't know exactly how to implement this. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you just want fractions, Python has them builtin. I'll try and get you an answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right; you need to implement `__neg__` because that minus is not the (binary) subtraction operator, but the unary minus.

Here is how you can do it:

```
    def __neg__(self):
        return Fraction(-self.numerator, self.denominator)
```

### Other issues

#### `__rsub__`

You need to change the implementation of `__rsub__`, because that method will be called when `other` does not support `__sub__`. For instance, it will kick in when you evaluate this:

```
p = 1 - Fraction(2, 3)
```

That evaluation will not work as it currently stands. You need to have this:

```
    def __rsub__(self, other):
        return Fraction(other) - self
```

or, explicitly calling `__sub__`:

```
    def __rsub__(self, other):
        return Fraction(other).__sub__(self)
```

#### Normalising

The constructor correctly normalises the fraction, making sure the denominator is positive, but you don't do the same in the `sub` method. There the result may not be normalised: the denominator could remain negative.

Moreover, it is a pity that you duplicate the gcd-related code that is already in the constructor. It is better to rely on the constructor for that logic.

#### Immutability

It is better to treat instances as immutable. So you should not have any assignments to `instance.numerator` and `instance.denominator` outside of the constructor. Make sure to first determine the numerator and denominator (without normalisation), and *then* call the constructor passing these as arguments.

### Comparisons

You may want to compare Fractions for equality or relative order. For that you can implement `__eq__`, `__lt__`, ...etc.

### Proposed code

Here is how I would do it:

```
def gcd(denominator, numerator):
    if numerator == 0:
        return denominator
    else:
        return gcd(numerator, denominator % numerator)

class Fraction:
    def __new__(cls, numerator=0, denominator=1):
        if isinstance(numerator, Fraction):
            return numerator  # Use this instance and ignore 2nd argument
        return super(Fraction, cls).__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, numerator=0, denominator=1):
        if isinstance(numerator, Fraction):
            return  # self is already initialised by __new__
        if denominator == 0:
            raise ZeroDivisionError
        div = gcd(abs(denominator), abs(numerator))
        if denominator < 0:
            div = -div
        self.numerator = numerator // div
        self.denominator = denominator // div
        
    def __str__(self):
        if self.denominator == 1:
            return str(self.numerator)
        else:
            return f"{self.numerator}/{self.denominator}"
    
    def __rsub__(self, other):
        return Fraction(other) - self

    def __sub__(self, other):
        other = Fraction(other)
        return Fraction(other.denominator * self.numerator 
                             - self.denominator * other.numerator,
                        other.denominator * self.denominator)
    
    def __neg__(self):
        return Fraction(-self.numerator, self.denominator)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        other = Fraction(other)
        return (self.numerator == other.numerator and
                self.denominator == other.denominator)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        other = Fraction(other)
        return (other.denominator * self.numerator <
                     self.denominator * other.numerator)

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return Fraction(other) < self

    def __le__(self, other):
        return self < other or self == other

    def __ge__(self, other):
        return self > other or self == other
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and you are absolutely right about implementing the extra binary operations, however when I run the written program I notice that an error occurs, do you know how I can fix this again?

Comment: What is the error and on which statement?

Comment: What is the error and on which statement? I don't see any error. See it run on [repl.it](https://replit.com/@trincottrincots/httpsstackoverflowcoma678615645459839)

Comment: That is indeed strange, I see that it does work on the forwarded link. If I copy both your entire code or only the part of the binary operations (and `__rsub__`) I get a TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'int' and 'Fraction'. I think there is something wrong with the GCD. Since this isn't really a post that gets a lot of views, I'll add my current (and therefore modified) code at the bottom of the question for now.

Comment: I see you did not include the `__new__` method, which I introduced, in order to capture a call where `other` in `Fraction(other)` is already a `Fraction`. Also, you didn't incorporate the corresponding change in `__init__`.

Comment: I think I've solved the problem, when I remove the lines (in the binary operations) where Fraction is called again, the code returns the desired result.

Comment: Yes, but that is less generic. The idea is that the difference between an int and a `Fraction` is resolved at a single place, which is in `__new__`. If you remove those `Fraction(other)` lines, you cannot do `p > 1` anymore, and similar things...

Comment: Okay yes I think I understand what you mean, but I also had this problem when I completely copied your code. However, I think it has to do with how I linked a fraction to a variable. I do this as follows: p = Fraction(4,5), q = Fraction(2,3) and print(p == q). Then it doesn't work. However, if I remove the Fraction recall and list the fraction as (4,5) or 4/5 it works

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. It runs fine with my code: [repl.it](https://replit.com/@trincottrincots/OtherCadetblueClasses#main.py). I want to stress that the code you copied into your question is not correctly reflecting my code.

Comment: That's right I know. Anyway, it works the way I want it to, so I'm very happy with that. Thank you so much for your help and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Your `__rsub__` code is flipped, you want `other.__sub__(self)`.

```
    def __rsub__(self,other):
        return other.__sub__(self)
```

Comment: So you mean it's best to replace `__rsub__` with `other.__sub__(self)`?

Comment: Yes, in your implementation (1-fraction) always flips to (fraction-1)